# WordPress WooCommerce words not translated

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to translate woo-commerce using WPML. I am translating woo-commerce in Chinese languages using .mo and .po files. Everything is translating fine but some words is not translted like quantity, Paypal, view cart etc. I try to translate it using string translator but not effected.

Any suggestion please.

Thanks

Comment: In Theme and plugin localization have you tried "Translate the theme and plugins using WPML's String Translation" option. And then scroll down and click the Scan button for themes and for plugins?

Comment: Yes i have done with this option.

Comment: After you have scanned the theme and plugins, the strings will appear in string translation to translate.

Comment: i got it. its done. Thanks

Comment: I have added my suggestions as the answer, if you don't mind marking it as correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In WPML -> Theme and plugin localization please select the option "Translate the theme and plugins using WPML's String Translation" option. After that, scrolldown and click the Scan buttons for both themes and for plugins.

Finally, after the operation completes, please go to WPML -> String translation and search for the strings you want to translate.